# Latex compilation error miktex-makepk -makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason METAFONT failed on ecsx0800

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I am getting error when compiling the Latex script for journal publication using Textudio  with MikTex. I am using standard ElseVier  single column template.

```
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\UMV\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
```

also I have read log where I find some logs like this

```
makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason
2023-03-15 23:18:08,442+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecsx0800.
2023-03-15 23:18:08,442+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecsx0800.
2023-03-15 23:18:08,442+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2023-03-15 23:18:08,442+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2023-03-15 23:18:08,442+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2023-03-15 23:18:08,470+0500 INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (10268) finishes with exit code 1
2023-03-15 23:19:01,085+0500 INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (6064) started by pdflatex in directory D:\MasoodThesisDefense\AugustPaper\29August with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose ecsx0800 525 600 0+525/600
2023-03-15 23:19:01,086+0500 INFO  miktex-makepk - running on Windows 10.0.19041
2023-03-15 23:19:01,091+0500 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font ecsx0800 at 525 DPI...
2023-03-15 23:19:01,105+0500 INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2023-03-15 23:19:01,124+0500 INFO  makepk - Creating ecsx0800.pk...
2023-03-15 23:19:01,132+0500 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2023-03-15 23:19:01,132+0500 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecsx0800"
2023-03-15 23:19:01,133+0500 INFO  miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecsx0800"
2023-03-15 23:19:02,599+0500 INFO  makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason
2023-03-15 23:19:02,600+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecsx0800.
2023-03-15 23:19:02,600+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecsx0800.
2023-03-15 23:19:02,600+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2023-03-15 23:19:02,601+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2023-03-15 23:19:02,601+0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2023-03-15 23:19:02,621+0500 INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (6064) finishes with exit code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a line

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

at the beginning of my LaTeX file solved the issues for me.